# Xamarin Forms / XAML: Converter not called

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anybody know why only the second `isvisible` converter gets called?
If I changed the sequence, then only the new second converter get called.
Converter1 is `DiaryTypeNahrungsaufnahmeToBoolConverter` and converter2 is `DiaryTypeAuswirkungToBoolConverter`.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>      
        <ViewCell>
            <RelativeLayout IsVisible="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource converter1}}"></RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout IsVisible="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource converter2}}"></RelativeLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The Converter code is:

```
public class DiaryTypeNahrungsaufnahmeToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is LibChemotherapie.DiaryType)
            {
                return ((LibChemotherapie.DiaryType)value) == LibChemotherapie.DiaryType.Food;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DiaryTypeAuswirkungToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is LibChemotherapie.DiaryType)
            {
                return ((LibChemotherapie.DiaryType)value) == LibChemotherapie.DiaryType.Effect;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: What is the code for your converters? As the question is stated right now, it is too broad, so there are too many possibly answers. Please add more details, otherwise it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: @Demitrian okay added the converter Code

Comment: Where have you defined `converter1` and `converter2`? Or did you simply use those names to avoid typing the names of the converters in your code for your question?

Comment: I think the problem is that your ViewCell has two children.  A ViewCell only has a single View property, so it can only have a single child.  Multiple children need to be enclosed in a single layout.

Comment: @Jason yeah thanks, that's it! Now it's working! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the hint from Jason, it's working now! I changed the xaml, so that the ViewCell only consists one view. In that view I added my two relative layouts with the binding property.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>      
        <ViewCell>
            <RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout IsVisible="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource converter1}}"></RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout IsVisible="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource converter2}}"></RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```